# Artifactory: List all Docker images in all repos using AQL

Tags: artifactory

I'm trying to get a list of all Docker images in all repos.
It is easy to do in GUI by navigating to the "Package view", choose "Docker" as package type and "*" as a name.
As result, it shows the perfect result as I want it - unique image name, repository, number of tags, and last modified.

I've tried to use an AQL to fetch it via API:

```
items.find(
  {
    "$and":[
      {"$or":[
        {"$and":[
          {"name":{"$eq":"manifest.json"}},
          {"$or":[
            {"@docker.manifest":{"$match":"*"}},
            {"@docker.manifest":{"$match":"library/*"}}
          ]}
        ]}
      ]},
      {"$rf":[
        {"$or":[
          {"property.key":{"$eq":"docker.manifest"}},
          {"property.key":{"$eq":"sha256"}},
          {"property.key":{"$eq":"docker.repoName"}}
        ]}
      ]}
    ]
  }
).
include("updated","type","created","actual_sha1","property.key","id","modified_by","size","actual_md5","depth","original_md5","created_by","modified","sha256","name","repo","property.value","path","original_sha1").
limit(1500)'
```

But as a result, it gives me images with its tags. I.E. if the image has 1000 tags - it will show them all in the output, while I need only a unique name of the images.

Answer (score 2):

Pls see an example for single repo:
https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/aql-query-to-get-all-images-in-local-docker-repository/

I believe it should be working for all repos as well.

Comment: Unfortunately - no, this doesn't work.
In the mentioned example we see a following code:

```"repo":{"$eq":"<docker repository name>"},```

We need to specify a repo name, and as result - it returns all images and all tags located in that repo.
Using wildcard as a name gives nothing.

Comment: Just remove the Repo from AQL: items.find(
{ 
"@docker.repoName" : { "$eq" : "*" }

}

).include("name", "@docker.repoName", "@docker.manifest" ,"stat.downloads")